# view controller doesn't respect "largeTitleDisplayMode"

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, preferslargetitles

It seems that I can't set `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always` unless I also set `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`? Is this intended behavior?

I'm having a really hard time believing apple would force me to manually set `largeTitleDisplayMode = .never` on every screen in the navigation controller, even ones I don't control, in order to get just a single screen to show with large titles.

Comment: _Is this intended behavior?_ answer is: yes, it's intended: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2909056-largetitledisplaymode

Answer (score 0):

You can try controlling this via [UINavigationControllerDelegate.willShow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate/1621878-navigationcontroller) calls like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
}

// Assumption: ViewController is rootViewController for the UINavigationController
extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let isRootVC = (viewController === self)
        viewController.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = isRootVC ? .always : .never
    }
    
}
```

##### UPDATE

The other option would be to do this same management on `viewWillAppear(_:)` & `viewWillDisappear(_:)` calls for the rootViewController instance in your navigation stack.

Comment: I'd rather not have to go a hacky route like this. There are instances where I may need the navigationController delegate and can't have it get overridden by every view controller

Comment: This is to be done on the `rootViewController` only - Not for every UIViewController subclass within that navigation stack.

Comment: It still overrides the navigationController delegate, which is kind of hacky and I don't want to do as it's going to lead to other problems. I just want to be able to set `largeTitleDisplayMode` for an individual view controller and have the navigationController respect that value

Comment: The other option would be to do this same management on `viewWillAppear(_:)` & `viewWillDisappear(_:)` calls for the rootViewController instance in your navigation stack. No solution is pretty here.